# Returns 403 error after user login

Tags: 7, commerce

My site was copied from production to test server. It works on Drupal 7 + Nginx + PostgreSQL. On production, user login works fine, but on test server I receive a 403 error on users/admin (or user/1) where I'm redirected after login.

What I've already checked/done:

1. Database tables cache_* and sessions are empty.
2. User *admin* in the database has: uid = 1, status = 1, roles = 2 (authorized), 3 (administrator), 10 (site admin)
3. Try to open in IE, Chrome, Firefox. All history (cache and cookies) were deleted.
4. In file sites/default/settings.php there are the variables `$base_url = "http://mytest.domain.com"`, and `$cookie_domain = "mytest.domain.com"`
5. nginx.conf contains such rules for 403 error:

   ```
   location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
       return 403;
   }

   location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
     return 403;
   }

   location ~ (^|/)\. {
     return 403;
   }
   ```

   Also all *fastcgi_cache* options are commented out.
6. Permissions on server: sites/default - 775 (folders), 644 (files); sites/default/files - 775 (folders), 644 (files).
7. Also I see that *login* field in the *users* table is updated when I login, but  the *watchdog* table and *sessions* table don't contain rows about the session being open.
8. php.ini: opcache.enable = 0

How can I fix the 403 error?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a problem. As I said, I'm new to this project and recently I've found that it uses a Memcache module to save sessions. But both *memcached* and *php5-memcached* were not installed on my test server.